# Getting buffer name in a shell script

Tags: vimscript, shell

I have a shell script meant to run within vim. I'd like it to insert the name of the file I'm editing but I can't figure out how to do it. Is there a way to, perhaps, call `bufname()` from within a shell script?

Comment: Could you pass the buffer name as an argument of your shell script?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I probably could, but that would be more keystrokes than inserting it after the script runs. `Shift-R`-`Ctrl-R`-`%` is fairly instant. I'm just looking for a way to be even lazier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do use environment variables:

```
let $BUFNAME=@%
!yourshellscript.sh
```

Use `$BUFNAME` within your shell script.

Remark: you could set an autocmd to set `$BUFNAME` when you switch to a window.

Comment: Well... that was easy. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)